# Sitecore Bucket issue with single character items

Tags: buckets

We are using Sitecore Bucket feature for folders where we have lots of items. One of the issue we are dealing with is if the item name is one character than bucket feature throws an error with the below details.

Any assistance - what could be causing this issue?

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
System.InvalidOperationException: An item can not be moved to itself. 
at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, Func`1 getMessage)
at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.MoveItemCommand.‏⁪⁯⁪‬‎⁮‪‫‎⁬⁭‍‎‍‌‪‍⁮‎‫‏⁪‪⁮‭⁬‍‪⁯‎⁫‬‬‍⁭‫‌‭‫‮(Item , Item ) at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.MoveItemCommand.‌‫⁫‬
‬‮‌⁯⁬‏‍‫⁫‪‪⁮‪⁫‫⁭‪⁭⁯‭⁪‍⁬‬‪‭⁭‭⁪‫​⁬⁪⁭‬‮(Item , Item ) at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.MoveItem(Item item, Item destination, SecurityCheck securityCheck) at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.BucketOperationProcessor`1.MoveItem(Item item, Item destination) at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.BucketOperationProcessor`1.MoveSingleItemToDynamicFolder(Item newParent, Item itemToMove) at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.BucketOperationProcessor`1.MoveItemToDateFolder(Item topParent, Item toMove) at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.CreateBucket.RunBucketingProcess.CreateBucket(Item item, Action`1 callBack, CreateBucketArgs args) at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.CreateBucket.RunBucketingProcess.Process(CreateBucketArgs args) at (Object , Object ) at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args) at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.CreateBucket.CreateBucketPipeline.Run(CreateBucketArgs args) at Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketManager.CreateBucket(Item item) at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.BucketItems.CreateBucketProcessor.StartProcess(Object[] parameters) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args) at (Object , Object ) at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute() at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)

ManagedPoolThread #19 14:22:35 INFO  Job started: Syncing Bucket
ManagedPoolThread #19 14:22:35 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\xxxxx): Sync bucket: master:/sitecore/media library/DAM/General Images, language: en, version: 1, id: {427DAB16-8DE1-4338-8923-13FAC1570467}
ManagedPoolThread #19 14:22:35 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

**Nested Exception :**

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: An item can not be moved to itself.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, Func`1 getMessage)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.MoveItemCommand.‏⁪⁯⁪‬‎⁮‪‫‎⁬⁭‍‎‍‌‪‍⁮‎‫‏⁪‪⁮‭⁬‍‪⁯‎⁫‬‬‍⁭‫‌‭‫‮(Item , Item )
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.MoveItemCommand.‌‫⁫‬‬‮‌⁯⁬‏‍‫⁫‪‪⁮‪⁫‫⁭‪⁭⁯‭⁪‍⁬‬‪‭⁭‭⁪‫​⁬⁪⁭‬‮(Item , Item )
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.MoveItem(Item item, Item destination, SecurityCheck securityCheck)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.BucketOperationProcessor`1.MoveItem(Item item, Item destination)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.BucketOperationProcessor`1.MoveSingleItemToDynamicFolder(Item newParent, Item itemToMove)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.SyncBucket.RunSyncProcess.SyncRec(Item current, SyncOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.SyncBucket.RunSyncProcess.SyncBucket(Item item, SyncBucketArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.BucketOperations.SyncBucket.RunSyncProcess.Process(SyncBucketArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Commands.SyncBucket.StartProcess(ClientPipelineArgs args)


10140 14:22:37 ERROR Assembly not found Cognifide.PowerShell
ManagedPoolThread #7 14:22:39 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
```

Comment: Is it for any bucket? or just a single bucket? Do you have any custom rule for creating a buckets folder path like https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-item-buckets-custom-folders-structure ?

Comment: No we do not have any custom Rule. the Bucket that i am trying to apply is for folder under media library which has few items including one item with c.png. if i rename c.png to c2.png than it works. If i rename it to c.png then same error appears.

Comment: I've checked on Sitecore 9.3 and it works with files like "c.png" or "a.png". Which version you use?

Comment: we are on sitecore version 9.2